# Swift - UISearchBar: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10297eabc)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I have an array and in this array I'm doing a search:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let textToSearch = searchController.searchBar.text!
        filteredData = feedItems.filter({($0.DesenNo?.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased()))!})
        listTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

When I tap on the search bar and type any letter or number, Xcode gives following error on filtering line:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10297eabc)

And also here is what I get on Debug screen:

> [2169:828959] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

I could not understand the problem and be able to solve it. There is not much things on internet. I hope you can help me, Thank you!

Comment: You have a forced cast (the ! ) at the end of your filter line. Likely trying to force cast your `$0.DesenNo?` which is an optional and does not exist at the time you run the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible problem is that you're using force-unwrapping for an optional value. Try this

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let textToSearch = searchController.searchBar.text, textToSearch.isEmpty == false {
        // update search results
    } else {
        // clear search results
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can be sure that `textToSearch` is not `nil` and not empty.

*UPDATE*

There is one more force-unwrap at this line

```
filteredData = feedItems.filter {
    ($0.DesenNo?.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased()))!
}
```

Your entities might not have `DesenNo` property. If they don't, you force unwrap will cause a crash. Filter your array like that

```
let lowercasedSearchline = textToSearch.lowercased()
filteredData = feedItems.filter {
    // Do not include items with empty DesenNo field
    guard let desenNo = $0.DesenNo else { return false }

    // filter items that has that field filled
    return desenNo.lowercased().contains(lowercasedSearchline)
}
```

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x104382aa4)
When I did the changes, this time I got this error..

Comment: @ErsTar Update my answer. Hope it helps now.

Comment: This solved my problem! I forgot that some of entities not have it and this is causing a crash. Thank you for your time and help